# Adding a custom devnet to remix

Tags: solidity, remix, evm, custom-errors, dev-chain

I am trying to deploy a smart contract to a new EVM Devnet with its dedicated ChainID. I've got the RPC endpoint, but when I try to add it as a custom External HTTP Provider in remix, I get an "Error while connecting to the provider, provider not connected" without any further explanation.

What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to add that custom network to MetaMask ?